# Why are some faces lighter than others?

Tags: normals, faces

As seen below, the faces in the centre are lighter than the others. All have the same material.  Recalculating the normals didn't help. What is causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Due to your smooth shading.

> Smooth shading fake smoothness by bluring the normals of faces,In some cases there isn't enough geometry to produce good approximation and this cause unexpected shading.

Here is a cube which is smoothed,It has very few faces which doesn't help in producing a good smooth results.

[image]

**Read my article [here](https://blendernpr.org/lets-talk-about-normals/) for full demonstration.**

Answer (score 1):

Omar's answer is one possibility, and would probably have been the one I offered as first choice. But looking at the screenshot, I see another possibility: it may be an artifact of the spacing of modeling elements the the area immediately to the right of the part area which appears lighter. My basis for offering this as a possibility is that the density of edges to the immediate right is much higher than the density of edges to the left of the area. I would check the denser area for duplicate vertices, edges, and faces.

Comment: Well, the problem in my case was this: I merged verticles at the faces junction into one in that area. Just didnt know this can breake shading so bad.